# How to initialize my model in order to check if saving is successful

Tags: flutter, dart

I have build a model for my Player.

```
class Player {
  String uid;
  String name;

  Player({
    required this.uid,
    required this.name,
  });

  factory Player.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    Map data = doc.data()!;
    return Player(
      uid: data['uid'],
      name: data['name'],
    );
  }
  factory Player.fromMap(Map data) {
    return Player(
      uid: data['uid'],
      name: data['name'],
    );
  }
}
```

How will I initialize the user if it failed on the TRY statement. Before, I just pass it as null value if it failed. Then this will be my checking if my saving is successful or not.

```
  @override
  Future<Player> saveProfile({required String uid, required String name}) async {
    try {
      DocumentReference ref = db.collection(Paths.playersPath).doc(uid);
      var data = {
        'uid': uid,
        'name': name,
      };
      ref.set(data, SetOptions(merge: true));
      final DocumentSnapshot currentDoc = await ref.get();
      user = Player.fromFirestore(currentDoc);
    } catch (e) {
      print('failed to save: $e');
      //TODO how will I initialize the user because what I have tried below does not work
      //user = new Player();
    }
    return user;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```dart
@override
  Future<Player> saveProfile({required String uid, required String name}) async {
    try {
      DocumentReference ref = db.collection(Paths.playersPath).doc(uid);
      var data = {
        'uid': uid,
        'name': name,
      };
      ref.set(data, SetOptions(merge: true));
      final DocumentSnapshot currentDoc = await ref.get();
      user = Player.fromFirestore(currentDoc);
    } catch (e) {
      print('failed to save: $e');
      final data = {'uid': uid, 'name': name};
      user = Player.fromMap(data); 
    }
    return user;
  }
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks for your help. I understand it now.